# How can I remove WooCommerce guest customers from WooCommerce Customers List

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a strange situation. I have started my store by allowing people to check out without needing to create an account. `Guest checkout`  So with every order, a customer was created in the customer section of the WooCommerce plugin. I no longer need those guest customers and I would like to delete. However, there is no option to do that anywhere.

`WooCommerce > Customers` option is introduced in WC 4

They have no users associated with them they are just customers. WooCommerce does not allow me to remove them.   I have tried everything. Even external plugins that are built to manage WooCommerce users, do not detect these customers.

```
DELETE FROM wp_users WHERE ID NOT in (1,2)
```

I have even tried WP-CLI and still those customers not deleted.

Cleared `wp_wc_customer_lookup` still showing the same.

It's like they're hiding as metadata somewhere or something. Any ideas?

Comment: There is no customers, only the orders you have to delete

Comment: I have deleted all the orders already. and my user list only has my as the admin. Yet when go to the sidebar woocommerce customer section, these mystery customers still remain. :( tried verything.

Comment: You need to clear wp_wc_customer_lookup

Comment: I did that, I removed those records manually and was almost sure they would be gone. But i refreshed the list on the site and they were there still :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('_transient_wc_report_customers_%')" );
```

Run this once.

Comment: i ran it 4 rows were affected. refreshed the list, the customers remain. What else can i try?

Comment: thank you mujuonly, it was a strange combination of both the above things.  I had to run the query,   then i had to wp_wc_customer_lookup (at that point customers were still showing) and finally i ran the above query again, which effected half the rows (donno where they came from) but after that, they were gone!  so huge thanks to you!